# Retrofit get List can't be worked into a String

Tags: java, retrofit

While producing a list of my Entity  I can't convert this to a String.

This is my Team code:

```
public class Teams {

    @SerializedName("teamName")
    @Expose
    private String teamName;
    @SerializedName("matches")
    @Expose
    private Object matches;
    @SerializedName("players")
    @Expose
    private Object players;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public Object getMatches() {
        return matches;
    }

    public void setMatches(Object matches) {
        this.matches = matches;
    }

    public Object getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Object players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

I'm using the following get:

```
public interface SoccerStatsApi {

    String jsonUrl = "https://soccerstatsapp.azurewebsites.net/api/";

    @GET("teams")
    Call<List<Teams>> getTeams();`
```

And this is where I want to convert it to a complete string:

```
Call<List<Teams>> call = soccerStatsApi.getTeams();                                 

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Teams>>() {                                          
    @Override                                                                       
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Teams>> call, Response<List<Teams>> response) {  }
```

Response().body().toString() only returns the initial string, not the actual object values in the List/response. I've checked everywhere, but so far no answer I can actually work with.

Answer (score 0):

cast Response.body() to List.
for example:
'''List teams = (List)response.body() ;'''

hope you have configured retrofit to use Gson as default json parser

Comment: This makes teams (in this case) an array list with objects inside, where the info of my JSON is put into. I still need to extract one of the fields, so that I can put this into a spinner. Example(https://imgur.com/a/WufRyc4)